# Node MySQL order of inserts

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am inserting images into my database using `mysql`.

The order that these images get put in the database is important. I know it is possible to have an `order` column but due to the logistics of the project I am unable to do this.

So, using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), I have maintained the order of my object with the result:

```
Map {
  0 => 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTc5WDg0Ng==/z/dMkAAOSwHcpaoorf/$_03.JPG',
  1 => 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTc5WDc4NA==/z/hVkAAOSwQ19aoorl/$_03.JPG',
  2 => 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTc5WDgxMQ==/z/-kYAAOSwYBxaoorO/$_03.JPG',
  3 => 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTgwWDgxMQ==/z/seAAAOSwxo9aoorR/$_03.JPG',
  4 => 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTgwWDEwMzA=/z/p1AAAOSwW5laoorU/$_03.JPG',
  5 => 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzY0WDExMTQ=/z/p10AAOSwW5laoorY/$_03.JPG',
  6 => 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTE4WDc3Nw==/z/Yq0AAOSwVExaoorb/$_03.JPG',
  7 => 'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTgwWDEwMzA=/z/mNMAAOSwfTVaoori/$_03.JPG' }
```

Great. So now to put these in the database:

```
data.images.forEach(function(image, j) {    

    let insert_image_query = "INSERT INTO images (file, is_external) VALUES ('" + image + "', 1)";

    mysqlQuery.executeQuery(insert_image_query).then(function (insert_image_response) {

    });


});
```

But they don't get put in in order, it's sometimes pretty random. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: MySQL rows don't have an intrinsic "order". You must give it some order when querying, with an `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise no order is guaranteed in any way…!? So, at what point exactly do you figure the order is "random"?

Comment: I suspect `mysqlQuery.executeQuery()` being asynchronous. I would recursively call another insert in the `.then()` method

Comment: They are being put in in the wrong order. Not retrieved.

Comment: mysqlQuery.executeQuery() _is_ asynchronous, yes - what can I do to maintain the order in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ECMA-262, 5th edition](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) specification and [MDN's `Array.forEach()` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) both show the algorithm for `.forEach()`, and it will definitely iterate over array elements in ascending index order (skipping indices that were never assigned a value), however execution times of particular requests may vary. Each call of the callback function you passed to the `.foreach()` does not last the same amount of time. They are all called in the order you hoped for, but since they are not synchronous, your code won't wait for the first one to finish before executing the next one.

Of course, some browsers may not implement that algorithm properly, but I'm not aware of any that don't.

To fix that you could wrap the whole thing into asynchronous function and await execution of each one separately

```
(async ()=>{
    for (let image of data.images){
        let insert_image_query = "INSERT INTO images (file, is_external) VALUES ('" + image + "', 1)";
        await mysqlQuery.executeQuery(insert_image_query).then(function (insert_image_response) {

        });
    }
})();
```

or using the `.reduce()` syntax

```
data.images.reduce(async (lastItemsPromise, image) => {
    await lastItemsPromise;
    let insert_image_query = "INSERT INTO images (file, is_external) VALUES ('" + image + "', 1)";
    return mysqlQuery.executeQuery(insert_image_query).then(function (insert_image_response) {

    });
}, Promise.resolve());
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysqlQuery.executeQuery()` being asynchronous, I would recursively call another insert in the .then() method, to ensure the datas are inserted in the correct order, such as :

```
function insert(images, index = 0)
{
    let insert_image_query = "INSERT INTO images (file, is_external) VALUES ('" + images[index] + "', 1)";
    mysqlQuery.executeQuery(insert_image_query).then(function (insert_image_response) {
        if (index + 1 < images.length)
            insert(images, index + 1);
    });
}

// first insert
insert(images);
```

---

Or, build a single query in a loop, and then execute it, this will improve performance, avoiding many requests to the database :

```js
const images = ['https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTc5WDg0Ng==/z/dMkAAOSwHcpaoorf/$_03.JPG',
              'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTc5WDc4NA==/z/hVkAAOSwQ19aoorl/$_03.JPG',
              'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTc5WDgxMQ==/z/-kYAAOSwYBxaoorO/$_03.JPG',
              'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTgwWDgxMQ==/z/seAAAOSwxo9aoorR/$_03.JPG',
              'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTgwWDEwMzA=/z/p1AAAOSwW5laoorU/$_03.JPG',
              'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzY0WDExMTQ=/z/p10AAOSwW5laoorY/$_03.JPG',
              'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTE4WDc3Nw==/z/Yq0AAOSwVExaoorb/$_03.JPG',
              'https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTgwWDEwMzA=/z/mNMAAOSwfTVaoori/$_03.JPG'];

let image_array = [];
images.forEach(function(image, j) {
  image_array.push("('" + image + "', 1)");
});
    
let insert_image_query = "INSERT INTO images (file, is_external) VALUES " + image_array.join(', ');

console.log(insert_image_query);
```

---

Note that this query is vulnerable to SQL injections, but I don't know that library and can't tell how to parameterize the query